# How to setup a current controlled current source (CCCS) in the electronics workbench tool

Tags: circuit-design

Implement this circuit in Multisim Electronics Workbench:

[image]

Can someone validate/check if the values measured by volt/ampere-metres are correct? and tell me how to approach such problem analytically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you how Multisim Electronics Workbench works. But in general, the current controlled current source in Spice uses this format:

```
F<xxx> <node+> <node-> <voltage source name> <gain>
```

This means you need to add a voltage source in series with the resistor and then identify that voltage source in the CCCS Spice card.

In LTspice, the schematic looks like:

[image]

The polarity of the voltage source, in the above case that's \$V_1\$, is crucial.  Since your \$I_x\$ is pointing up, it's vital that this arrow tip points at the (+) terminal of the voltage source, as shown.

Then, if you look over at the CCCS (\$F_1\$) you will see the name of that voltage source and then, next to it, the gain.

If Multisim follows the standard Spice card formats, it's likely to support a similar schematic item. That said, schematic symbols and diagrams are not part of Spice itself nor is there a standard for schematic drawing programs which hide the Spice cards, so it's possible that Multisim does something unusual. Look to the documentation for details.

You were asking about the trick. That's the trick.

Here's the resulting netlist from the above visual diagram. The following is what Spice really uses when analyzing the schematic. Not the diagram itself, but the following netlist:

```
R1 N001 0 6k
F1 0 N001 V1 2
I1 0 N001 24m
V1 N002 N001 9
R2 N002 0 2k
```

Note the F-card above? It identifies the voltage source to look at for a current that it will apply a gain to. It doesn't accept resistor names, though. Only voltage source names. Just the way it works.

Comment: but how do you link the CCCS with the 0 V source?

Comment: sorry but i think you did a mistake a linked a UPS Tracking in the plato-demonstration, also im very confused by what you've said i've only asked on whats the purpose of the 0V source and how to link it with the CCCS

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Thanks. Error fixed: "You need to think in terms of society and people when graphics displays literally did not exist (or, perhaps like the [Plato demonstration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLATO_(computer_system)) was just barely being created) and this was all done with a deck of [punched cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card). You don't get to use a graphical link. I know that's what your world, today, says to you. But it wasn't that way, back when Spice was developed. All that's needed is the NAME of voltage source. See it there as part of a value of F1?"

Answer (score 0):

The CCCS needs to be controlled by the current flowing through the 2kOhm resistor so the workbench circuit is incorrect. the CCCS inputs must be placed in series with the 2kOhm resistor using some trick so as not to alter the voltage across it.

Comment: how do i do that trick that you said?

Comment: Basically you have to place a resistor with a value lower than 1_Ohm in series with the 2k resistor in order to make the effect on the voltage across the 2k resistor insignificant. The voltage drop across this new resistor is proportional to the current flowing through it. This voltage drop drives a signal conditioning circuit made up of an operational amplifier in a non-inverting configuration, whose output voltage varies in the voltage range allowed by the CCCS input.