# Analysis of dependent current source

Tags: circuit-analysis

I’m trying to use both mesh analysis and node's current law to demystify this circuit: [image]

We have 3 nodes, two upper nodes and one supernode at the bottom between the two sources, so we have 2 equations: since the two resistors are in parallel they must have the same voltage let’s denote it: \$ V \$
then we have: i found out that \$ V = 14.4 V \$ now to verify that this valid, i have to sum all the electrical power of each device in the circuit and it should be zero, so \$i_2 = \frac{V}{2000} = 7.2 mA\$ and \$ i_1 = \frac{V}{6000} = 2.4 mA \$
so \$ P_{24mA} = - 24 * 10^{-3} * 14.4 = -0.3456 W \$ and \$ P_{2I_x} = - (2*7.2*10^{-3})*14.4 = -0.20736 W \$ not sure why i removed the negative sign from the current because i would end up with a positive power (meaning the device is using instead of generating energy)
and \$ P_{2k \Omega} = 2000 * (7.2*10^{-3})^2 = 0.10368 W \$
and \$ P_{6k \Omega} = 6000 * (2.4 *10^{-3})^2 = 0.03456 W \$
but the sum isnt exactly instead it is negative. whats wrong here?

Comment: There are two nodes. But one of them should be assigned to ground. So really only one unknown node voltage.

Comment: @periblepsis so there is only two nodes??

Comment: Well, since you think there are three, you must have a different meaning for node than I do. How do you define a node?

Comment: @periblepsis a node is a position in circuit in which 2 or 3 or more wires connects to which makes the current splits

Comment: Everything galvanically tied together into the same zero ohm metal connection is just one node and all of it must be at the same voltage.

Comment: so you are telling me there is only two nodes somehow you are saying the the node A is the same as node B, and node C is the ground? @periblepsis

Comment: Suppose I slid your node B over to the left until it was right on top of your node A. What happens if you merge the two into a single 4-way connection? In your mind, I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148435/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-periblepsis).

Comment: Related, if not identical: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/680604/how-to-setup-a-current-controlled-current-source-cccs-in-the-electronics-workb

Comment: @winny its related but not the same question, in that question i tried implementing the circuit in multisim i achieved that

Comment: Why don't you apply nodal analysis? Only one node voltage is unknown. Thus we have $$\frac{V}{6k\Omega} + \frac{V}{2k\Omega} - 0.024A - 2*(-\frac{V}{2k\Omega}) = 0 $$ And all we need is to solve for V. [link to the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=V%2F6+%2B+V%2F2+-+24+-+2*%28-V%2F2%29%3D0+)

Comment: @G36 In chat, that's what I wrote to them. They say they got it, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, the circuit we want to analyze is given by:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgfIyI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
0&=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
0&=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_0+\text{I}_1
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
0&=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_\text{a}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{0 == n*I2 + I1 + I3, I3 == Ia + I2, I0 == Ia + I2, 
   0 == n*I2 + I0 + I1, I1 == (V - 0)/R1, I2 == (V - 0)/R2}, {I0, I1, 
   I2, I3, V}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> (Ia (n R1 + R2))/(R1 + n R1 + R2), 
  I1 -> -((Ia R2)/(R1 + n R1 + R2)), 
  I2 -> -((Ia R1)/(R1 + n R1 + R2)), 
  I3 -> (Ia (n R1 + R2))/(R1 + n R1 + R2), 
  V -> -((Ia R1 R2)/(R1 + n R1 + R2))}}
```

Now, we can find:

$$\text{V}=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{a}\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{n}\right)+\text{R}_2}=-\frac{\displaystyle24\cdot10^{-3}\cdot6\cdot1000\cdot2\cdot1000}{\displaystyle6\cdot1000\left(1+2\right)+2\cdot1000}=-\frac{72}{5}=-14.4\space\text{V}\tag4$$

Comment: Bus the answer is 14.4V not  -14.4V.

Comment: exactly the answer is 14.4 not -14.4

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI I put the current source the other way around (by excident), take a look in my circuit. This will fix the problem :).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do complete node analysis.

You can write down this equation:
V = 2 * Ix = -Ix * 2kOhm

This only holds true for Ix=0 (and V=0).

Comment: what do you mean it only holds for such case ? if Ix = 0 then the circuit is trivial no?

Comment: Yes, because the equation above has to be fulfilled, the circuit is trivial, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary analysis of the circuit:
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLApFW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: whats the law that gave you the right to switch the position of the 6k ohm resistance to the right-most part of the circuit in parallel with the 2k ohm resistance?

Comment: The devices are all in parallel and subjected to the same potential difference, so they can be arranged as desired.

Comment: but you have used the current divider to calculate I_y , instead i just did I_y = V/6000 , and go another value different from yours, so whats clicking here? also let me tell you why i think you are wrong, do you think that the current 2I_x will return to its source to even apply the KCL in your transformation?

Comment: Sorry, I have to make a correction in my post.